# Compiler error, cannot find symbol, same code as other method

Tags: java, compilation

I'm writing a program with the MVC architecture, and I have this class Controller calling Manager's methods.

I get the following error  :

```
C:\(...)\java\packageController\Controller.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    return manager.validerStat(a);
symbol:   method validerStat(int)
location: variable manager of type Manager
1 error
```

What I don't get is, I called the validerStat int using auto-complete in netbeans, and other methods called just like this also work.

Controller's code :

```
package packageController;

import packageException.ExceptionBD;
import packageModel.*;
import packageBusiness.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controller {

private Manager manager;

public Controller() {
    manager = new Manager();
}


public boolean validerStat(int a) {
    return manager.validerStat(a);
}

public boolean validerNomCarte(String s){
    return manager.validerNomCarte(s);
}
}
```

Manager's code :

```
package packageBusiness;

import packageException.ExceptionBD;
import packageModel.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Manager {

public Manager() {
    db = new packageDataAccess.RequetesDB();
}

public boolean validerStat(int a) {
    return a > 0;
}

public boolean validerNomCarte(String s){
        return s.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+");
}
}
```

Comment: Is everything saved? refreshed? etc.

Comment: Everything is saved and I get no error prior to compiling, I even copy/pasted the methods header to make sure there is no typo what so ever, but no dice

Comment: Do you have more than one class named `Manager`?  That is the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: You should also make sure that you "clean" your output before you try again (delete your `.class` files).

Comment: ^ That was it, an old .class that wasn't getting recompiled, thanks a lot Jason